# Entity Framework auto generate primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework. I have a simple class:

```
 public class User
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //public UserList Users { get; set; }

    public User() { }
    public User(int userId, string email, string username)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        Email = email;
        UserName = username;
    }
}
```

And my Initializer class:

```
public class UserDataInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UserDataContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(UserDataContext context)
    {
        var Users = new List<User> {

            new User() {UserId=1, Email="a1@gmail.com", UserName="a1", Password="123456"},
            new User() {UserId=2, Email="a2@gmail.com", UserName="a2", Password="123456"},
            new User() {UserId=3, Email="a3@gmail.com", UserName="a3", Password="123456"},
            new User() {UserId=4, Email="a4@gmail.com", UserName="a4", Password="123456"}}


        Users.ForEach(i => context.Users.Add(i));
        context.SaveChanges();


    }
}
```

Suppose, i want add new User with UserId=100. It will auto change UserId to 5.

**How i can disable this modification of EF?** 'UserId' must be primary key and it's type is int.

Comment: Use on UserId`[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki Thanks!

Comment: If your database has AutoIdentity enabled, you might want to disable it first before inserting your own ids: `_dbContext.AutoIncrementOff(nameof(_dbContext.Users));`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to change your attribute in `User` class to:

Data annotations:

```
 [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerat‌ed(System.ComponentM‌​odel.DataAnnotations‌​.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOp‌​tion.None)]
 public int UserId { get; set; }
```

or Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(m => m.UserId)
         .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```