# asp.net | How to add data to a database's next Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i've recently started learning programming/asp.net web apps and ran into a small problem.

I have a class consisting of 2 properties - string Name and byte Id

I'm trying to add data through web app to my database (adding a name) and it adds name to an id of 0 instead of adding to the next id (if there are 3 ids and 3 names, i want the new name to be added to id 4 and etc)

I think the problem is because in my class the id is initialized as a byte instead of int ? and it can't add i presume ?. (i have another "add method" for another class and everything works there, the only difference is the other id is an int)

My code for savind data :

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCategory(CategoryFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var id = _context.Category.Max(p => p.Id);
        var category = new Category
        {
            Id = id++,
            Name = viewModel.Name
        };

        _context.Category.Add(category);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

With this code i get an exception that it tries to add data to an existing id (the latest), i tried changing the `"Id = "`, i tried `"Id = viewModel.Id"` but then it adds to id 0,  maybe someone can help me :), ty in advance!

Error :

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Categorys'. Cannot insert duplicate key
>   in object 'dbo.Categorys'. The duplicate key value is (4). The
>   statement has been terminated.

Comment: When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to include that error. An error that occurs at runtime this case its called an `Exception` (*this is how errors manifest themselves in .net*). Include the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursively across `InnerException`s all the way down. Use the  [edit] link on your question to include that detail, do not include it as a comment. Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *Don't* try to specify the ID in your code. If you are using SQL Server specify that the ID column is an IDENTITY column and the key will be generated automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework auto generate primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278167/entity-framework-auto-generate-primary-key)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried not specifying the ID in my code and my ID column is recognized as a key, however same problem occurs - when i save changes, everytime it saves to ID of value 0, i also tried adding the Data Annotations but it's still the same, maybe i don't understand something?.

Comment: Check the duplicate question and any Entity Framework tutorial.

Comment: is your primary key field an identity field with auto increment? If it's not, it needs to be. And make sure Entity Framework knows that.

Comment: @ADyson Correct, that fixed the problem, does byte not get recognized as an identity or did i make a mistake with my code somewhere? Because after some code-rewriting i changed my Id from byte to int and after a migration it was an identity and everything worked just as with my other table.

Comment: Not sure you can auto-increment a byte field...there's no obvious sequence that the server can apply. Makes no sense you were using byte in the database though, when you were using a number in the code...int is by far the better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create new record it has `id=0` and after `_context.SaveChanges()` your record falls into database where id receives appropriate value. But it has to be identity!

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is with the `i++` in:

```
 var category = new Category
 {
     Id = id++,
     Name = viewModel.Name
 };
```

`id++` returns the value of `id` and then increments it by 1. This means you are trying to insert the maximum value already in the data base. Instead you should use either:

```
++id
```

if you want to increment the value of `id`

or:

```
id + 1
```

if you don't.

Comment: Ah, thanks, this does work, although im not sure if it's the correct approach, but i'll try to figure it out, for now this works, so thanks!

Comment: it'll work when you haven't got two users trying to do the same thing at the same time. There's a reason why you let SQL handle the creation of IDs...

Comment: If you want to keep setting the Id in code I'd recommend using a GUID rather than an int for the same reason as @ADyson

Comment: @SBFrancies there's no need for GUIDs. This code is simply wrong and theres' *nothing* wrong with post incrementing. Pre or post, next time this code runs the variable will be initialized to *0* and the same values will be created. Even if you load `id` from the database, eg with `MAX(id)` , it will *still* generate the wrong values if anyone deletes the last record. Using an autogenerated ID is trivial

Comment: @ems19 no, it doesn't work. If the record with the maximum ID gets deleted, you'd end up with broken relations. Never use such a technique

Comment: @emw19 the correct way is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278167/entity-framework-auto-generate-primary-key). A single line.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If there were relations enforced by foreign keys it would not be possible to delete the record with the maximum ID.