# EF - Save Changes - How to fix VIOLATION OF PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to add data into a table in sql.
I have the below class and method to add the new records.
But I am getting the below error.

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK__Users__3214EC27E90BFE7E'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (0). The statement has been
>   terminated.

```
public partial class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

}        


    public void InsertUser(MyEvent e)
    {
        using (var db = CreateInstance())
        {
            var users = db.Set<User>();
            users.Add(new User
            {
                Name= e.Name,
                Surname= e.Surname                    
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
         }
      }
```

How can EF auto-increment the ID in the table?

Comment: Just a question, you *did* configure that column in the database as an identity column, right? The attribute just says "this will come from the database", you also need to make sure the database actually generates a new value.

Comment: it is for MS SQL Server

Comment: See this: [Entity Framework auto generate primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278167/entity-framework-auto-generate-primary-key)

Comment: Go To Database And Make sure the field Id Is Identity in the table.If Not.You Should Update-Database For Applying Changes.

Comment: Primary keys so be create in the stored procedure in the database and not in c# code.  there are lots of articles on web about using stored procedures to generate unique IDs.  You can have a cluster of SERVER and each server should have a unique prefix to avoid different server creating duplicate keys.  When you have a single server with multiple users you have to avoid tow clients from using the same Primary ID so you have to use a stored procedure which has a lock so only one user at a time can create the next available ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the SQL server itself incrementing the PK, not the EF. If you have multiple EF clients inserting data into the DB at the same time, it would be difficult to ensure the PK is incremented correctly. With SQL it is much easier, all you need to do is set the PK column as identity with auto-increments.

If the PK column is row_id, you can define it like this via scripting:

```
[row_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Or, if you create the table using SSMS designer, then in the column properties set Identity Specification as:

```
Is Identity = Yes
Identity Increment = 1
Identity Seed = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `DB` and just define as:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

without any Data Annotations